# SQL server Can I pass the results of a table- valued function to a stored procedure?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a conceptual way I'd like to code a set of related functions and stored procedures. I'm hoping to get a little feedback on whether or not that way is doable.

In a stored procedure, I'd like to assign the values of a table-valued function to a temporary table, then pass that table to another stored procedure...

Can I do this without creating table types?

Comment: Usually it's best to give it a go and come back when you run into a problem.  It really shouldn't take you but a few minutes to code a test up.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675163.aspx

Comment: I'm confused. Why not just have the other stored procedure reference the table-valued function? You could probably do this easier with table-valued parameters but it seems like overkill to shuffle that data around multiple times.

Comment: @AaronBertrand I'd prefer that way, but in this case, unless I don't understand how the table- valued function would work, it'd requery the table involved every time it's called, which has millions of rows... I want to use that same exact set of results in several sprocs in a row, so shouldn't I just retrieve it once?

Comment: If you insert the results of the table-valued function into a table-valued parameter, it just passes the data to the other procedure, it doesn't re-query. I'm not sure about how it all works (haven't really used them) but I still don't get why you don't just have the other procedure call the table-valued function. Or dump the results to a #temp table (a stored procedure you call will be able to see the #temp table).

Comment: You'll get much better specifics about TVPs and other methods of sharing data between procedures here : http://www.sommarskog.se/share_data.html

Comment: @AaronBertrand Thanks, great article, I just found it a few minutes ago. My thought was every time the table valued function is used, it's invoked I'd assume, which would requery. I'll read that reference you just posted again..

Comment: Yes but why do you need to call the table-valued function more than once? (Please note the distinction between table-valued function and table-valued parameter in my previous comments.)

Comment: @Aaron Gotcha. I'd like to pass the data returned from a table- valued function to several stored procedures that each takes a table- valued parameter.. if instead of passing in the table containing the needed data, each sproc referenced the function, it'd be redundantly retrieving the same data, 5000+ times (once per stock symbol) from a table with millions of rows, across 10+ sprocs. I thought my idea would grab that data once up front. You mention that the reference of the table valued function doesn't requery when it's passed, I'm not understanding the order(s) of execution then..

Comment: If you use a table-valued parameter, I really don't think the TVF would be invoked again. The whole point of the TVP is to pass around a set of data, regardless of how it was populated. You'll have to test it.

Comment: @AaronBertrand Temp table it is, thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick sample of the #temp table solution:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.B
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT * FROM #foo;
END
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.A
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT TOP 1 * INTO #foo FROM sys.objects;

    EXEC dbo.B;

    DROP TABLE #foo;
END
GO

EXEC dbo.A;

DROP PROCEDURE dbo.A, dbo.B;
```